# Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.0.2 vs. 2.14.4)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined, js engine: hermes

ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
```

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes